# how to add cookieDomain with the google analytics in ember?

Tags: ember.js, google-analytics

I have installed the Google Analytics plugin in my ember app. But in the plugin cookieDomain is set to none by default. How can I change the cookie domain value?

Here is my code:

```
 return ga('send', 'pageview', {

     'page': this.get('url'),

     'title': this.get('url')

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit in the curly brackets is a configuration object for a GA method. It takes key/value pairs where the key is the name of a configuration option in Google Analytics and the value is the intended value of that configuration. So passing in the cookie domain would work analogous to setting page and title (although Ga retrieves page and title by default, and it seems odd to set the title field to the url value). So you would create a key/value pair for the cookie domain:

```
return ga('send', 'pageview', {
     'cookieDomain':'auto'
 });
```

This is not specific to Ember.